# Grails 2.5.5 access request and params from a filter method

Tags: grails

In Grails, request and params are available inside the filters, but if a util method is defined in the filter, request and params are not available from the method and I need to pass them as parameters to that method.

I would like to access request and params without the need of passing them every time to every method in my filters, is that possible?